# Can XSL-FO flip (mirror-image) characters?

Tags: fonts, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I looked at the XSL-FO font attributes in [the spec](https://www.w3.org/2002/08/XSLFOsummary.html) under 6.6.3 `<fo:character>` and I don't see anything that will let me reverse a character. I can rotate it 180 degrees but that is not the same thing.

I want to be able to do the equivalent of CSS `transform: scale(-1, 1);` for instance.

Something like (using the made-up `font-scale-horizontal`):

```
Click the <fo:inline xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-weight="bold" line-height="100%" font-family="MaterialIcons" font-scale-horizontal="-1"></fo:inline> next to the...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AH Formatter, you could use `axf:transform` (see https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf65/ahf-ext.html#transformation), otherwise you probably have to do it as an SVG graphic.